# Android Runtime Logcat only get current instance

Tags: android, multithreading, logging, runtime, logcat

I need some help with my readLog process.
My app has a service executed with AlarmManager every 1 minute and writing logs in its execution like this:

```
Log.i("MyTag", "current value from database " + currentValue);
```

My ReadLog Service is a independent service running with AlarmManager every 5 minutes.

I am doing like this:

```
String cmd = "logcat -d";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

but when I get logs from my ReadLogs Service I only get Logs from actual/last service execution. My android studio Logcat messages shows something like this:

```
08-01 12:00   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 1
08-01 12:01   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 2
08-01 12:02   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 3
08-01 12:03   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 4
08-01 12:04   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 5
08-01 12:05   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 6
08-01 12:06   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 7
...
```

And my ReadLog service shows something like:

```
08-01 12:00   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 1
08-01 12:05   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 6
08-01 12:10   31716-8894/my.package I/MyTag﹕ current value from database 11
...
```

Reading something about it I figure out that the problem may be that when I execute Runtime.GETRUNTIME I only get "Current Runtime" and not all available logs of my app.

Comment: If you check with your computer instead, did the logs roll over?

Comment: Logs in computer are as shown first, they are not rolling over. If figured out that if I stop my first service (reading current value from database), logs read ok. As there is only one instance of my app running.